# Transform to map with predictable order

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream, collect

I have following code:

```
users.stream()
                .sorted((u1, u2) -> u2.getScore().compareTo(u1.getScore()))
                .limit(count)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap((User::getName), (User::getScore)));
```

Content of result is right  but when I want to foreach it - it output in unpredictable result. I think it is because under the hood HashMap is used.

Is there way to collect to mp with predictable result?

Comment: Use `toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper, Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper, BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction, Supplier<M> mapSupplier)`, and make the merge function throw an exception if it didn't suppose to happen.

Comment: @Alexis C. I should not provide merge function. I have unique names

Comment: That's why I said to throw an exception in the merge function.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
           return users.stream()
            .sorted((u1, u2) -> u2.getScore().compareTo(u1.getScore()))
            .limit(count)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap((User::getName), (User::getScore), (k, v) -> {
                        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Duplicate key %s", k));
                    },
                    LinkedHashMap::new));
```